# Can laser radiation cause Faraday rotation?

Tags: electromagnetism, laser

Let a vertically polarised beam of laser light pass, at right angles, through a horizontally polarised beam of laser light of much greater wavelength.

Does the oscillating magnetic field of the one cause Faraday rotation in the other?

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/783276/what-happens-when-2-laser-beams-cross

Comment: I think you are confused about what the Faraday effect actually is. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faraday_effect - the second laser beam is not a medium for propagation that would exhibit a magnetic permeability.

Comment: Thank you Jon Custer :)

Comment: Not quite sure how to say I'm grateful for the answer to my question. Thank you Jon Custer:)

Comment: I have read a little bit more and discovered that, for a laser beam to be rotated, it must pass along the same path as a magnetic field.